# Android CCAVENUE without address

Tags: android, ccavenue

I want to integrate ccavenue with my application as a payment gateway. But I don't want to accept user's billing or shipping address. In fact I don't want to accept any kind of address. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: have you find any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

```
There are 3 approach in ccavenue 

 1) nonseemless and seemless where you have to add address in the ccavenue page 
2) frame base where you have to not add address just add this like in your form submit page

 <tr>
                    <td>Integration Type    :</td><td><input type="text" name="integration_type" value="iframe_normal"/></td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: is there any iframe available in android also ?